# Can I use several wireless range extenders in cascade?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

I am trying to extend the range of my home network to reach both floors above mine. I've been given 3 linksys re1000 range extenders but I can't understand if they can work in a cascade. I can get one working perfectly fine, but fail with the others. It looks like the second extender I add further away tries to connect to the main router (thus having poor to none signal) instead of the first extender (which gives a good signal as I tested with my laptop).

Is it possible to make them work in sequence? Any particular configuration needed?

Comment: I would be doubtful.

Comment: Can you log into the extender and tell it to connect to a specific MAC address? That way it should definitely connect to the right connection. Bare in mind if you are jumping through 2 or 3 range extenders back to your router you may find your connection won't be too fast or stable.